# Visual Studio 2019 C++ project error "A dependent dll was not found", how to know which dll is not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I found several others are puzzled by this matter as well, but no answer is satisfying. I am inheriting a big C++ program set up in Visual Studio 2019, it builds fine, but when running it, the studio complains "A dependent dll was not found" without any other useful info.
Is there anyway to know which dll is needed, or even which symbols are not found?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Short answer - no. Windows simply does not provide this information.  Longer answer - try using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what file is being searched for when the error happens.

Comment: Maybe: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to determine the dll dependencies of your application.

Comment: This is very frustrating. I feel astonishing that Windows and Visual Studio have such incomplete (inferior) feature!

Comment: @xycs The debugger is sometimes not the only tool a developer needs

Comment: I agree with you PMF. But in a corporate environment, sometimes it is very difficult to import another tool. Visual Studio or Windows should be able to remind which dll or names are not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dependency Walker, I have identified the missing DLL. It does not require installation, very good to use.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)